# Angular Provider - $http is not defined when $get return object

Tags: angularjs, angular-http, angular-providers

if `$get` configured like so :

Config :

```
.config( function( authProvider ){
    authProvider.initial();
})
```

Provider :

```
.provider('auth', function() {

  this.initial = function() {
    obj.user = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('user') );
  }

  var obj = {
    get: function() {
      return this.user;
    },
    set: function( userData ) {
      this.user = userData;
      localStorage.setItem( 'user', JSON.stringfiy( userData ) );
    },
    send: function( data ) {
      $http.post( 'user/' + data )
        .then(  res => {  //  Arrow Functions 
          this.set(res.data);
        };
    },    
  };

  this.$get = function( $http ) {
    return obj;
  }

})
```

I get `$http is not defined` Error - When `send()` calling

And if it like so :

```
.provider('auth', function() {

  // This method will not work !
  this.initial = function() {
    obj.user = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('user') );
  }

  this.$get = function( $http ) {
    return
    {
        get: function() {
          return this.user;
        },
        set: function( userData ) {
          this.user = userData;
          localStorage.setItem( 'user', JSON.stringfiy( userData ) );
        },
        send: function( data ) {
          $http.post( 'user/' + data )
            .then(  res => {  //  Arrow Functions 
              this.set(res.data);
            };
        }    
    };
  }
})
```

I do not have an error

But `this.initial()` Does not work.

because it can not access an object that a `$get` method return ..

So my questions is :

1. Why in the first example gives me an error at all ?
2. how should I do it ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Is there a real reason why `authProvider.initial()` is necessary in config block? You can't have service instances ($http) in service providers and config blocks. This is chicken/egg causality dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

@estus is spot on with the service/provider issue. The [docs on providers](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/a4e60cb6970d8b6fa9e0af4b9f881ee3ba7fdc99/docs/content/guide/providers.ngdoc#L249-L254) tell us that when providers are instantiated, services do not exist yet. And when services are being created, interaction with providers is disallowed.

From the docs:

> During application bootstrap, before Angular goes off creating all services, it configures and
>   instantiates all providers. We call this the configuration phase of the application life-cycle.
>   During this phase, services aren't accessible because they haven't been created yet.
>
> Once the configuration phase is over, interaction with providers is disallowed and the process of
>   creating services starts. We call this part of the application life-cycle the run phase.

Seems like you need to create a service/factory rather than a provider if you need access to other services.

---

Also, as to why `this.initial` will not work, a provider *only* exposes what is returned in the `$get` method.